# sublime text 2 portable update not sure how?

Tags: windows, sublimetext2, updates

I have just (finally) started using **sublime text 2**, and I am liking it so far (apart from lack of intellisense / autocompletion :(, though tried codeintel but its not what I expected), I am moving from netbeans (can't afford to use it because of memory eating nature :(). Anyway My current issue is I don't know how I can use latest update of sublime text 2 (portable on **windows**), it kept prompting me about update and once I listened to it and it downloaded new version but there was no step involved in actually updating the **existing** version to new one instead I have another portable version with newer files, and my issue is i have install several plugins in the old version and I don't know how I can use those in this new version :(.

Note: It just started saying me this version has **expired** so thats why I am seeking help so I can use new version but with my already installed plugins (emmet, js minifier etc etc :().

I have googled alot but found no windows based guide which helps me solve my issue :(.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to extract to the portable directory (as the location). I believe it will override the necessary files.

Comment: Yes you are right, but this way I have a chance of loosing configurations, preferences or settings I have on my current version :(.

Comment: Unless you are modifying the built in packages, it should be fine. Well, just moving the data folder as MattDMo suggested also works. If you used package control to install packages, you can simply move the User folder (which contains Package Control.sublime-settings). Simply install package control on the new portable version and package control should grab any installed packages for you.

Comment: Will do as suggest on next update and see which works.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that your old version is installed in `Sublime.old`, and the new version in `Sublime.new`. Make sure Sublime Text 2 is closed, then move the `Sublime.new\Data` folder to someplace else (like your Desktop, for now), just in case anything breaks. Then, *copy* (don't move) the `Sublime.old\Data` folder to `Sublime.new`. Fire up the program and check to see that everything is there, and works properly. Please note that this method **will not** work when upgrading from ST2 to ST3, as there are major differences in the way plugins are run.

Comment: This method involves risk factor, as there are several files (folders) which comes with latest version and are also present in old version like (like inside packages folder, and Prestine Packages folder etc), though what I did is copied none existing projects (emmet, js minifier, etc etc) into my new version, but I am not sure how I can import old settings etc (I would like to move things as is apart from core files)

Comment: @Syed There is no "risk factor", as the packages are all the same. Most of your settings should be stored in the `Data/Packages/User` folder, so you should move that to your new install location.

Comment: Hmmmmm okay I will try this on next update and will let you know. (as I have moved files manually (long way :() already).

Comment: as MattDMo already said, ther's no risk factor.
Your settings resides under X:\something\SublimeText2\Data\Packages\User and default settings (I've done some changes there too) are under X:\something\SublimeText2\Data\Packages\Default.
By saving those directories you prevent any preference's loss.